# select image and and play an audio by clicking the button using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<audio id="audio1" src="a.wav"></audio>
<audio id="audio2" src="b.wav"></audio>

<img id="img1" src="a.png" alt=""  onselect="select()"  />
 <img id="img2" src="a.png" alt=""  onselect="select()"  />  

<input type="button"  onclick="play()">
```

i have multiple images in my code a and every image has its respective audio what i want to do is i want to select the image and   on clicking the button  i want to play the audio against that particular image .all this i want to do using javascript and html . so can any one help me javascript part?

Comment: What in particular is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this and it should work:

```
<img id="img1" src="a.png" alt=""  onclick="select(this.id)"  />
 <img id="img2" src="a.png" alt=""  onclick="select(this.id)"  />  

<script>
  function select(num){
       var x = num.match('/\d+/');
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio"+x);
       audio.play();
                 }
</script>
```

Comment: It should play audio after button is clicked, not image. So you should firstly remember the image which was selected and only after button is pressed - play audio.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using data attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/bostdgvp/

JS:

```
var selectedImage;

function select(image) {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    var index = 0, length = images.length;
    for (; index < length; index++) {
        images[index].classList.remove('selected');
    }
    selectedImage = image.id;
    image.classList.add('selected');
}

function playAudio() {
    if (!selectedImage) {
        alert('no image selected')
    }
    var image = document.getElementById(selectedImage);
    var audioId = image.getAttribute('data-audio')
    var audioElement = document.getElementById(audioId);
    audioElement.play();
}
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio1" src="@Url.Content(item.Letter_Record)"></audio>
<audio id="audio2" src="@Url.Content(item.Letter_Record)"></audio>
<img id="img1" data-audio="audio1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" onclick="select(this)" />
<img id="img2" data-audio="audio2" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" onclick="select(this)" />
<input type="button" value="play" onclick="playAudio()">
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: FYI, I've taken your fiddle and improved it a bit, if you don't mind. If you think my answer is plagiarism, I will delete it.

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld HOW DARE YOU!! just kidding. Of course not. We are all here sharing ideas and learning from one another. I always say if I didn't learn something new about coding every day I am not doing my job, so I am sure my answers can be improved on. In short....be my guest =]

Comment: Haha, well it's been a hot item on SO lately, so I was just preventing  any meta posts from being made haha. Already posted the answer! Maybe you can improve it even further

Comment: @dania you're welcome! if you feel this helped you or answered your question I would not mind it being accepted as the answer =]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle that should put you in the right direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/knopch/31oasnee/

```
<img id="img1" src="a.png" alt=""  onclick="select(this.id)"  />
<img id="img2" src="a.png" alt=""  onclick="select(this.id)"  />  

<script>
    function select(id){
      console.log(id);
      //play(id);
    }
</script>
```

This allows you to click the image, and its id will be printed in the console (option+cmd+j on chrome+mac).
So if you have the id of the object being clicked (or selected), the select() functions really just need to pass on this id to the function that handles playback. If you have an audio file mapped to each image, you can select the audio file for playback based on the image id.